# How to find MySQL records having one field's content within any row of another field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The problem is simple. Is there a MySQL query allowing, in a single table, to **find all records having some content within any row of another column ?**

In other words, I have a table with 2 columns : "FirstName" and "LastName".

My automatic filler has melted some of them.

So I would like to find all occurences of "LastName"s that also appear in column "FirstName".

That way, all the Doe JOHN would be detected, because "John" must 100% be in the list of "FirstName"s, whereas John DOE would not be detected, because there is nearly no chance to find DOE as a first name...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE FirstName LIKE 'John' OR LastName LIKE 'John'` is this what you need?

Comment: Poor old Elton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM nametable
WHERE firstname IN (select lastname FROM nametable)
```

That will find row where the first name exists as a last name in the table.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed. Here is my final request

SELECT * FROM `clients_table` WHERE `lastname` IN (SELECT firstname FROM `clients_table`)

That way, rows are directly editable in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 2):

Just perform a self join over the table. It should look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    CUSTOMER C1
        INNER JOIN
    CUSTOMER C2 ON (C1.FirstName = C2.LastName OR C1.LastName = C2.FirstName);
```

Comment: Works well, as much as smullan's answer. Yours seems faster, but a little more complex to understand. Does not allows edition using phpMyAdmin too. Big thank